# ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull a cell from a Pandas `DataFrame` using it's index, and saving to another `DataFrame`.

```
for n in range(len(df)):    
    yesterday, beach= df.loc[n,['Full_date','Beach']]
    ts=datetime.datetime.strptime(yesterday,'%Y-%m-%d')
    day_sub = ts-td(days=1)
    two_days = str(day_sub.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    try:
        df.loc[n,'2_day_prior_Escherichia.coli']=pd.to_numeric(df_beach.loc[(two_days,beach),'Mean'])
    except:
        df.loc[n,'2_day_prior_Escherichia.coli']=np.nan
```

Where `Full_date` is in a `YYYY-MM-DD` format, `Beach` is a string of the name of a beach, and `Mean` is an object that is essentially a float.

When I run this code the

```
pd.to_numeric(df_beach.loc[(two_days,beach),'Mean'])
```

comes up with a `ValueError`:

> Incompatible indexer with Series.

Any idea as to why this is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: `'Full_date'` is string, not smth in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Do you mean `df.loc[n,['Full_date']]`? Please clarify the wording